# Fatal error: Call to a member function api() on a non-object

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm running this code and I'm getting the following message:

"Fatal error: Call to a member function api() on a non-object in"

The line it refers to is the one just below where I write `global $facebook`.  The facebook object is initialised in a config.php file which I include in my Database.php file, which I have linked in. I have researched this problem and it seems that it comes about when your `$facebook` is declared outside a function and you use it inside without making it global.  As you can see, I have made it global, and I have even tried doing it without making it global - both result in that error.

Does anyone know why?

p.s. I don't even see why it needs to be global since if config.php is included in my Database.php file, and that is included in the code below, then isn't the $facebook object within the scope of this code?

```
<?php
    include_once('../../Database.php');


    session_start();    // Start session for safety

    // Retrieve the user's current shortlist of potential flatmates
    $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    $shortlistRes = getShortlist($uid);

    global $link;
    $shortlist = null;
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($shortlistRes)) {
        $shortlist[] = $r;
    }
    var_dump($shortlist);
    // Create array of parameters you need
    $parameters = array("pic_square");


    // Get id and picture of everyone on shortlist

        $shortlistString = implode(",",$shortlist);
        $fql = "SELECT uid, pic_link FROM user WHERE uid IN ($shortlistString)";
        global $facebook;
        $shortlistFBInfo = $facebook->api(array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => $fql
        ));
        print_r($shortlistFBInfo);






    // Display Shortlist Page
    //include_once('../View/shortlist_v.php');


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code are you actually instantiating the `$facebook` variable - the sample code distributed with the SDK does so like this:

```
 require_once("facebook.php");

  $config = array();
  $config[‘appId’] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
  $config[‘secret’] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
  $config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

Comment: Hey Igy - I mentioned that there is a Database.php file that is included at the top of the page and within this it includes a config.php file which initialises the Facebook object - so technically it should be within the scope of this!

Comment: I'm a little rusty on php scoping but i don't think you should need to declare it as global if it's included in another file at the same level